# OpenLayers/Angular . In the my map i am trying to change the style when i click on a Feature. How do i change the style of the Vector

Tags: angular, typescript, openlayers

Here create my Feature:

Typescript--

```
  addScanLayer(data: [number, number][][]) {
        let id = 1
        for (let scan of data) {
          let multigon = new MultiPolygon([[scan]]) // Does there exist a better way than saying [[data]]?
          let scanFeature = new Feature({ geometry: multigon, id: id })
          let scanLayer = new Vector({
            source: new VectorSource({ features: [scanFeature] }),
            style: this.scanLayerStyle
    
          })
          this.Map.addLayer(scanLayer)
          id++;
        }
      }
```

As you can see I apply a style to the new Vector. I use a for loop to draw my shapes.

Then I use event to get data for click:

HTML--

```
<div (click)="getCoord($event)" class="map-container" id="map"></div>
```

Typescript--

```
  getCoord(event: any){
   this.Map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(this.Map.getEventPixel(event), (data, rem) => {
     var getId = data.getProperties()
     if(getId.id){
     this._passDataTimelineToZgsMapsService.sendDataIndex(getId.id)
    }
    })
 }
```

Now in the documentation it gives a example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-hover-features.html

The Example:

Javascript--

```
let selected = null;
map.on('pointermove', function (e) {
  if (selected !== null) {
    selected.setStyle(undefined);
    selected = null;
  }

  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function (f) {
    selected = f;
    selectStyle.getFill().setColor(f.get('COLOR') || '#eeeeee');
    f.setStyle(selectStyle);
    return true;
  });

  if (selected) {
    status.innerHTML = selected.get('ECO_NAME');
  } else {
    status.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
  }
});
```

but when I do it I get error

typescript--

```
 getCoord(event: any){
   this.Map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(this.Map.getEventPixel(event), (data, rem) => {
     var getId = data.getProperties()
     data.setStyle(this.scanLayerStyleSelected)
     if(getId.id){
     this._passDataTimelineToZgsMapsService.sendDataIndex(getId.id)
    }
    })
 }
```

The error:

```
Property 'setStyle' does not exist on type 'RenderFeature | Feature<Geometry>'.
  Property 'setStyle' does not exist on type 'RenderFeature'.ts(2339)
```

So how do I change a specific vector style ?

Comment: forEachFeatureAtPixel can return both features (from a vector layer) or RenderFeatures (from a vector tile layer).  As you have only a vector layer you will have features, but you must typecast if using typescript.

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use a style function, which would avoid having to call `setStyle()` https://codesandbox.io/s/select-hover-features-forked-crvfv?file=/main.js